# CKAN - Different datasets

Tags: python, ckan

I am starting to get involved with CKAN. Until now I have done some of the tutorials and currently I am installing some of the available extensions.

Does anybody know if there is any other extension for customizing metadata datasets fields according differences between datasources?

In example:

- Uploading text files or documents like PDF: only I want 5 concrete
  metadata fields to be requested
- Uploading CSV files with Coordinates Fields (georeferenced): I want
  10 fields requested metadata fields. These fields could be different
  fields than PDF's ones.

In fact, I would like to add a new page where the user could specify first the tipology of the datasource and then the application could request for those fields which are necesary to be requested.

I have seen how to customize In the tutorial a schema with some extra metadata fields but I don't know how to work with different metadata schemas. And also this [extension](https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-scheming) could be useful for customizing dataset fields.

But, does someone have any idea about how to have different schemas depending of the type of a dataset?

Thanks for helping me :)

Jordi.

Answer (score 1):

I think with the ckan-scheming extension you get everything you want.

As you can see in [their documentation](https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-scheming#example-dataset-schemas), you can specify different schemas according to your needs:

- [Camel](https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-scheming/blob/master/ckanext/scheming/camel_photos.json)
- [Standard dataset](https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-scheming/blob/master/ckanext/scheming/ckan_dataset.json)

Feel free to create your own, customized schema, with exactly the fields that you need.

Once you have your schema (in fact you want to create two different ones, one for the text files and one for the georeferenced CSVs), you can simply use the generated form to enter those specific types of datasets.

The important bit here is, that you specify a new type of dataset in the schema, e.g. `{"dataset_type": "my-custom-text-dataset",}`. If everything is configured as it should be, you can find and add your datasets here: http://my-ckan-instance.com/my-custom-text-dataset